# order_create() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: django, celery

I was trying to do a celery task, the code as follows.

task.py

```
from .models import OrderItem
from cart.cart import Cart
from .forms import OrderCreateForm

@task(name="create_order")
def create_order(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save()
            for item in cart:
                try:
                    OrderItem.objects.create(order=order,
                                             product=item['product'],
                                             price=item['price'],
                                             quantity=item['quantity'])
                except:
                    pass
                cart.clear()
            return None
    else:
        form = OrderCreateForm()
    return None
```

views.py

```
from .models import OrderItem, Order
from cart.cart import Cart
from .tasks import create_order


def order_create(request, order_id):
    order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
    cart = Cart(request)
    create_order.delay(order.id)
    return render(request,'orders/order_created.html', {'cart': cart, 'order': order})
```

urls.py

```
from .views import order_create


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^create/$',order_create, name='order_create'),
    ]
```

When executing the code I am getting the error 'order_create() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)'. Hope somebody can help me to solve it. Thank you.

Following is my working code which sends mail after an order is created, but I wanted to change the entire view function as a celery task.

```
@task(name="send_mail_to_custormer")
def order_created(order_id):
    order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
    subject = 'Order nr. {}'.format(order.id)
    message = 'Dear {} {},\n\nYou have successfully placed an order. Your order id is {}'.format(order.first_name,
                                                        order.last_name, order.id)
    from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
    to_email = [order.email]
    mail_sent = send_mail(
                            subject,
                            message,
                            from_email,
                            to_email,
                            fail_silently=False
                          )
    return mail_sent
```

views.py

```
def order_create(request):
cart = Cart(request)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        order = form.save()
        for item in cart:
            try:
                OrderItem.objects.create(order=order,
                                         product=item['product'],
                                         price=item['price'],
                                         quantity=item['quantity'])
            except:
                pass
            cart.clear()
            order_created.delay(order.id)
        return render(request,'orders/order_created.html', {'cart': cart, 'order': order})
else:
    form = OrderCreateForm()
return render(request, 'orders/order_create.html', {'cart': cart, 'form': form})
```

Comment: Can we see your urls.py file?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with the task; `order_create` is the view itself.

Answer (score 0):

Change URL definition to below URL, you have missed passing order_id as parameter to the view

```
url(r'^create/(?P<order_id>\w+)/$',order_create, name='order_create'),
```

and you should pass the order_id with the url.

Comment: This pattern throws the error "Reverse for 'order_create' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: "

Comment: The API call should look something like https://domain/create/1234/ If 1234 is your order_id, Can you tell us how are you making the API call?

Comment: I have a working code in which celery task sends mail after an order is created, but what I wanted is to change all the view function to celery task